# using maximize in contraint

Tags: optimization, scheduling, cplex

[image]

If  (Ci > di), then t takes positive values. Otherwise, t value equals to zero (ti = max(0, Ci − di)).

[image]
it seems that i have an error when using maximize in constraint
it seems that i have an error when using maximize in constraint
it seems that i have an error when using maximize in constraint

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical expression (2) is wrong. You mean

```
 t[i] = max(C[i]-d[i],0)
```

This can also be modeled as:

```
 min sum(i, t[i])
     t[i] >= c[i]-d[i]
     t[i] >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use maxl:

t[i]==maxl(0,C[i]-d[i])

Full example at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomaxl.mod

```
int nbKids=300;

{int} buses={30,40,50};


dvar int+ nbBus[buses];
dvar int maxNbOfBusesGivenSize;

    
minimize maxNbOfBusesGivenSize;
     
subject to
{
 // logical constraint
 // maxNbOfBusesGivenSize is the max of all nbBus
 //maxNbOfBusesGivenSize==max(i in buses) nbBus[i];
 
 // but instead of max we ca use maxl for a list
 maxNbOfBusesGivenSize==maxl(nbBus[30],nbBus[40],nbBus[50]);
 
 
 sum(i in buses) i*nbBus[i]>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The max number of buses is ",maxNbOfBusesGivenSize);
  writeln("nbBus = ",nbBus);
}
```